# How to use JavaScript to switch all specific href links on page to something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to place some simple JavaScript/jQuery in my header as an added bit of spam protection on my website. Suppose I have a spammer posting a specific URL and I want to rewrite it whenever it shows up.

I tried this (in this example, I am trying to change all of a specific link on the page to google.)

```
$("a[href='http://www.spamsite.com/']").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/')
```

But the above didn't work.

Comment: The above code should work if you run that jQuery after jQuery is loaded and after the DOM is loaded or after the relevant content is added to the page and the href matches your target EXACTLY.  Please reproduce your issue in a jsFiddle so we can see the specific situation that does not work.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually the code will *only* work if the link is *exactly the same* as that with a trailing slash and `http://` at the start. There are alternatives.

Comment: It seems to work have you included jquery? https://jsfiddle.net/fj4tb20x/. I think you should validate for spam urls before saving. Also what if they went   "http://www.spamsite.com#5345345"?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - yes, that's why my comment says "EXACTLY".  Until the OP shows us enough of the actual code and HTML to know why it isn't working for them, all we can do is guess what might be wrong.  For all I know, they're just running the jQuery before the content is in the DOM.  That's a possibility too.  Lots of guesses when the OP doesn't show us enough of the actual code.

Comment: two things were wrong. The issue with exactness and the jquery needs to run in the footer not the header so it can run last as the href a tags were being produced by a php script. Thank you very much all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector requires an *exact match*, there are a couple of options you can have,but the best is to use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("a[href*='//www.spamsite.com']").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/')
```

This finds every link that has the string `'//www.spamsite.com'` and changes it, but it would also get links like:

```
<a href="http://google.com?s=//www.spamsite.com">Search for spam</a>
```

Other options include the [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("a[href^='http://www.spamsite.com']").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/')
```